# Foreach inside While Statement (NumRows)

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, mysql-num-rows

I'm trying to figure out how I would do a foreach statement inside my while statement. As you can tell by this code, it will only submit 1 row out of the table, even though it selects all the rows. How would I make it select each row?

Code:

```
$q2 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ticketreply` WHERE `ticketid`='$id'"));
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($q2);
while(count($num_rows) > $i){
    echo "<div style='float:left;width:940px;margin-bottom:2%;margin-left:".($i + 1)."0px;margin-right:25%;'><div style='margin-left:".($i + 1)."0px;border:1px solid #cecece;padding:10px;'>Posted By: <a href='#'>".user2($q2[1])."</a><h2>".$q2[2]."</h2></div></div></div>";
    $i++;
}
```

New Attempt:

```
$q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ticketreply` WHERE `ticketid`='$id'");
$i = 0;
foreach($q2 as $s){
    echo "<div style='float:left;width:100%;margin-bottom:2%;margin-left:".($i + 1)."0px;margin-right:25%;'><div style='margin-left:".($i + 1)."0px;border:1px solid #cecece;padding:10px;'>Posted By: <a href='#'>".user2($s[1])."</a><h2>".$s[2]."</h2></div></div></div>";
    $i++;
}
```

Although now this doesn't display any rows.

Comment: First of all try to avoid using of `mysql_*` functions.Instead use `mysqli_*` functions from php > 5.3

Comment: do you see foreach there ? or I'm missing something?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array does not return all results in an array. It returns one row, every time you run it again it will return the next row.

Did you check the php manual? Example #2 shows you how to use these functions.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: @AlirezaFallah i think he is asking us how to put foreach in there

Comment: Yes @krishna. And I see what you mean Jeroen, so I will take out the fetch array and instead do a foreach?

Comment: why do you want to use foreach instead of while() loop.

Comment: Just trying to learn how to @Krishna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ticketreply` WHERE `ticketid`='$id'");

$i = 0;
while ($s = mysql_fetch_array($q2, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    echo "<div style='float:left;width:100%;margin-bottom:2%;margin-left:".($i + 1)."0px;margin-right:25%;'><div style='margin-left:".($i + 1)."0px;border:1px solid #cecece;padding:10px;'>Posted By: <a href='#'>".user2($s[1])."</a><h2>".$s[2]."</h2></div>   </div></div>";
    $i++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, your query, `SELECT * FROM`ticketreply`WHERE`ticketid`='$id'` is most likely only selecting one row from the table.  I'm assuming that the `ticketid` in your `ticketreply` table is unique.  So there is only one row selected.

If I go with this assumption, then...

`mysql_fetch_array` fetches all of the **columns** from a single row returned by a query.  Documentation on `mysql_fetch_array` can be [found here](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array).

I would recommend, before you dive right into outputting your HTML and styling, start first with some print statements of `$q2`, to see that it really contains what you expect it to contain, and has the structure that you expect it to have.

Try:

```
$q2 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ticketreply` WHERE `ticketid`='$id'"));
print_r($q2);
```

You should see that $q2 is an array that is both integer-indexed and also string-indexed (that is, it is also a hash where each column name in your table is a key).  Let's restrict `mysql_fetch_array` so that it just gives us the associated array (the string-indexed part) and not the integers.

```
$q2 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ticketreply` WHERE `ticketid`='$id'"), MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Now, you can access each element of `$q2` as a key-value pair by the following:

```
foreach ($q2 as $column => $value) {
  print "column name: $column\n";
  print "      value: $value\n";
  print "\n";
}
```

If, instead, you don't care about the column names, and you just want an integer-indexed array of values, then you can do the following:

```
$q2 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ticketreply` WHERE `ticketid`='$id'"), MYSQL_NUM);
```

Then, you can use a regular `for` loop for iterating through your result...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($q2); $i++) {
   print "Value $i: " . $q2[$i] . "\n";
}
```

Once you get a good feel for what the structure of `$q2` is, then you will probably feel pretty comfortable and confident outputting your HTML with values from `$q2` embedded in the right place.

Comment: It is not unique. Its essentially just taking the ticket you're replying to and putting the ID of it inside the database. Although I see what you mean but its select more than 1, its select all of them when I var_dump.